# how to use case_when and grep together to define a new varaible

Tags: r, case-when

I have a data that looks like this,

[image]

It can be build using codes:

```
df<-structure(list(Gender = c("M", "F", "M", "F", "F"), Location = c("Cleveland, OH", 
"New Olreans, LA", "Chicago, IL", "Strongsville, OH", "Boston, MA"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I want to build variable" comment" as follow:
[image]

The rule is:
if Gender=="F" and we find "OH" in Location, then comment ="Female in OH"
if Gender=="F" and we can't find "OH" in Location, then comment ="Female in Other"
if Gender=="M" and we find "OH" in Location, then comment ="Male in OH"
if Gender=="M" and we can't find "OH" in Location, then comment ="Male in Other"

So my codes are

```
 df<-df %>% 
     mutate(Comment = case_when(Gender=="F" & grep("OH", df$Location)~"Female in OH",
                            Gender=="F" & !grep("OH", df$Location)~ "Female in Other",                        
                            Gender=="M" & grep("OH", df$Location2)~ "Male in OH",
                            Gender=="M" & !grep("OH", df$Location)~ "Male in other)",
                            TRUE~NA))
```

It won't work. Could anyone give me some guidance on this?

Comment: Use `grepl` rather than `grep`. The former will return a Boolean value as desired, the latter returns the indexes of the matches which is not what you seem to be expecting.

Comment: I tried `grepl` and still get the error code `Error: must be a character vector, not a logical vector`

Comment: Three other things: (1) don't use `df$` within the `mutate`, it is almost certainly wrong; (2) change your last `NA` to `NA_character_`; (3) Change your typo `Location2` to `Location`.  With those three changes, it works for me. (BTW: *"it won't work"* is not at all helpful. If you include the literal error text in your question, it often helps a lot more.)

Comment: Your last `TRUE~...` is not necessary, though, since the default action of `case_when` if there are no matches is to assign the class-specific version of `NA`. (Did you know there are at least seven types of `NA`?)

Comment: Thanks. I put `TRUE~ ` in just in case I missed anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grepl` rather than `grep` to get boolean TRUE/FALSE values rather than the indexes. For example (as well as fixing other typos)

```
df %>% 
     mutate(Comment = case_when(Gender=="F" & grepl("OH", Location)~"Female in OH",
                            Gender=="F" & !grepl("OH", Location)~ "Female in Other",                        
                            Gender=="M" & grepl("OH", Location)~ "Male in OH",
                            Gender=="M" & !grepl("OH", Location)~ "Male in other"))
```

I took out the NA part since you covered all the cases and NA is the default value when no other matches occur. But if you need it explicitly, then you should use the typed version of NA for characters.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Comment = case_when(Gender=="F" & grepl("OH", Location)~"Female in OH",
                             Gender=="F" & !grepl("OH", Location)~ "Female in Other",                        
                             Gender=="M" & grepl("OH", Location)~ "Male in OH",
                             Gender=="M" & !grepl("OH", Location)~ "Male in other",
                             TRUE~NA_character_))
```

Comment: The default action given no matches is to assign an `NA`, so that addition is mostly declarative and "complete", it produces the same results as without it.

Comment: @r2evans Good to know. I should have tested it.

Comment: I wasn't certain of it until I tested it, too :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be a bit simplified instead of checking every possible condition.

```
vec <- c('M' = 'Male', 'F' = 'Female')

transform(df, Comment = paste(vec[Gender], 
                       ifelse(grepl('OH', Location), 'in OH', 'in Other')))

#  Gender Location         Comment        
#  <chr>  <chr>            <chr>          
#1 M      Cleveland, OH    Male in OH     
#2 F      New Olreans, LA  Female in Other
#3 M      Chicago, IL      Male in other  
#4 F      Strongsville, OH Female in OH   
#5 F      Boston, MA       Female in Other
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a variant on @Ronak Shah's answer.
State abbreviation is discovered with `str_extract` and `"OH"` as the focal state is parameterized.

```r
gender_vec <- c('M' = 'Male', 'F' = 'Female')
state_map <- function(s, target = "OH") if_else(s == target, s, "Other")

df %>%
  mutate(Comment = str_c(recode(Gender, !!!gender_vec), "in", 
                         state_map(str_extract(Location, "(\\w{2})$")), 
                         sep = " "))
```